# How to add a footerview with loading in a UItableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have made an UITableView and I am fetching data from JSON from a webservice.

Firat, I want that I get first 5 objects first and load them in my tableView.  That is happening properly.

Then I want that whenever the user scrolls to the footer ..the next 5 objects should be fetched and it should be shown in tableView..

I am stuck here ..can anyone give me any idea how to proceed next?

My tableview has all custom cells loading from the custom classes for different types?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section==[array count]-1)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:mtableview1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        frame =  cell.contentView.frame;
        footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];
        footerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        self.activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] autorelease];
        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped=YES;

        self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(65,50);
        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

        UILabel* loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        loadingLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
        loadingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:87.0/255.0 green:108.0/255.0 blue:137.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        loadingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        loadingLabel.text=@"Loading.......";
        loadingLabel.frame=CGRectMake(95,35, 302,25);

        loadingLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        loadingLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        [footerView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
        [footerView addSubview:loadingLabel];
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadending) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        [loadingLabel release];

        NSLog(@"%f",mtableview1.contentOffset.y);
        mtableview1.tableFooterView=footerView;

        return footerView;
    }
    return nil; 
}
```

I have been doing it like this, but its position is not correct all the time.  That's my big issue.

Comment: :You need like Load More in the Bottom rite ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below concept.Concept is when user pull the table view then reload the additional data like pull to refresh.

```
Code Sample :
//MARK: -UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= - 65.0f) {
        // fetch extra data & reload table view
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving the proper way of implementation for the problem solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    }
```

in scrollViewDidScroll Method you can check row index for call you loading method

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.myTable indexPathsForVisibleRows]objectAtIndex:1]; //in middle visible of row
int visibleRowIndex = indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase **Number of rows** In table View when you reach to the last row check do you have more content to show or not. If u have MOre content to show then increase number of rows.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

After increasing number of row you can scroll to the desired row which you wann to show...

Answer (score 0):

I already implement this please look this here is my code

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(footerView == nil)
    {
        footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        if (ObjApp.checkDevice == 1)
        {
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoadMoreBtn.png"]
                              stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:8 topCapHeight:8];

            btnLoadMore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btnLoadMore setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            if(screenBounds.size.height == 568)
            {
                //    iPhone 5
                [btnLoadMore setFrame:CGRectMake(74, 13, 148, 34)];
            }
            else
            {
                //    iPohne 4 and Older iPhones
               [btnLoadMore setFrame:CGRectMake(74, 13, 148, 34)];
            }
        }
        else if (ObjApp.checkDevice == 2)
        {
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoadMoreBtn_iPad.png"]
                              stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:8 topCapHeight:8];

            btnLoadMore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btnLoadMore setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnLoadMore setFrame:CGRectMake(220, 26, 296, 67)];
        }
        [btnLoadMore.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
        [btnLoadMore setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnLoadMore addTarget:self action:@selector(btnLoadmore_clicked:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [footerView addSubview:btnLoadMore];
    }
    return footerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (ObjApp.checkDevice == 1)
    {
        return 47;
    }
    else
    {
        return 100;
    }
    return 0;
}

#pragma mark - Button Click Methods
-(void)btnLoadmore_clicked:(id)sender
{
    if(page > 0)
    {
        sendpage++;
        if(sendpage<= page)
        {
        [self loading];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data={\"name\":\"%@\",\"lat\":\"%f\",\"page\":\"%d\",\"long\":\"%f\"}",txtSearchFld.text,ObjApp.current_Latitude,sendpage,ObjApp.current_Longitude];
        [WebAPIRequest WS_Search:self :urlString];

        CGFloat height = tblSearchResult.contentSize.height - tblSearchResult.bounds.size.height;
        [tblSearchResult setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, height) animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```